# Sum if Bold with criteria in google sheet

Tags: google-sheets

I have used google script below

```js
function sumWhereIsFontWeight(rangeSpecification,) {

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);

var x = 0;

for (var i = 1; i <= range.getNumRows(); i++) {
for (var j = 1; j <= range.getNumColumns(); j++) {

var cell = range.getCell(i, j);

if(cell.getFontWeight() == 'bold')
x += parseFloat(cell.getValue());
}
}

return x;
}
```

Then used formula `=SUMIF(A:A,"A"&sumWhereIsFontWeight(B1:B6),B1:B6)`

But cannot get the desired result "10" of sum only bold numbers with criteria as "A". Check the image attached

[image]

Answer (score 1):

## Usage

`=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(isbold("A1:B10"),A1:B10,0)))`

## The function

```
function isBold(rangeSpecification) {

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var range = sheet.getRange(rangeSpecification);

  var result = [];

  var numRows = range.getNumRows();
  var numCols = range.getNumColumns();
  var row = [];
  for (var i = 1; i <= numRows; i++) {
    row = [];
    for (var j = 1; j <= numCols; j++) {
      var bold = (range.getCell(i,j).getFontWeight() === 'bold');
      row.push(bold);
    }
    result.push(row);
  }  

return result;
}
```

## Caution

A custom function won't update automatically when you add new bold cells. You need to re-enter the formula.

Comment: The formula you have given works! but it gives the sum total of bold without the criteria. I want to add the criteria of "A" and gives the sum of number (bold) value, that corresponds to A. That means the result should be 10.

Comment: `=ArrayFormula(SUM(IF(isbold("B1:B10") * (A1:A10="A") ,B1:B10,0)))`

Comment: Perfection!  Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your welcome! Please consider accepting the answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Now this function is throwing an error:
Exception: Invalid argument: range
ISBOLD @ Code.gs:4